# Can you attach an adorner's position to anywhere other than the upper-left of the adorned element?

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner, adornerlayer

I can't find any way of fixing an adorner to another point of the adorned element, other than the upper-left point. I know you can move the adorner relative to this point, by implementing ArrangeOverride, but the co-ord system is always based on the top-left.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. But there is one more possibility to position the Adorner content than ArrangeOverride: [AdornerPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.adornerpanel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). With it's [AdornerPlacementCollection Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.adornerplacementcollection_methods%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

- PositionRelativeToAdornerHeight Method
- PositionRelativeToAdornerWidth Method
- PositionRelativeToContentHeight Method
- PositionRelativeToContentWidth Method
- SizeRelativeToAdornerDesiredHeight Method
- SizeRelativeToAdornerDesiredWidth Method
- SizeRelativeToContentHeight Method
- SizeRelativeToContentWidth Method

you can determine the position and size of your Adorner relative to adorner or content e.g. with a factor and an offset. See this sample to place the Adorner above the adorned control:

```
// create AdornerPanel and add your adorner content
AdornerPanel adornerPanel = new AdornerPanel();
adornerPanel.Children.Add(yourAdornerContent);

// set placements on AdornerPanel
AdornerPlacementCollection placement = new AdornerPlacementCollection();
placement.PositionRelativeToAdornerHeight(-1, 0);
placement.PositionRelativeToAdornerWidth(1, 0);
AdornerPanel.SetPlacements(adornerPanel, placement);

// create Adorner with AdornerPanel inside
Adorner adorner = new YourAdorner(adornedElement)
{
    Child = adornerPanel
};
```

Comment: This opens a few doors. Thanks for the interesting and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution was perfect for me 
http://blogs.telerik.com/xamlteam/posts/08-05-22/wpf-series-creating-generic-adorner.aspx